# Video play through with scroll. And have it play through certain seconds trough the video

Tags: javascript, scrolltrigger

I have this video

```
<div class="intro "></h1>
        <video class="appVideo" src="https://b3ui01.myraidbox.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/lushroom_hero_sequence_prev_002_60fps.mp4"></video>
    </div>
```

and this codepen here using scroll-trigger, https://codepen.io/sikke/pen/YzdvXLw. where it works like this right now. When you scroll it scrolls through the whole video. but I want a different effect.

I want it to do this " when the user scroll downs, it triggers the video to play and it should play trough from 0 to 9s of the video. then pause the video. then it should on the next scroll down play through 9 to 14s. and continue to do the same. on 22s to 35s, 35s to 42s, 42s to 53s. and when the video ends it should be normal scroll again to the rest of the site" in the example I only use a short video. but u get the idea.
I don't want to share the video I'm gonna use.

(it don't have to be scroll-trigger to solve this question)